# Reference Wiki page from inside customized work item

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, tfs-workitem

I have created a customized work item. It there any way to link this work item with pre-created wiki page. I don't want to link it with work item manually, just kind of automatic link when create a new work item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient workaround is to create a custom field for your work item. And create a rule to automatically set the wiki page url as value of the custom field.

Check tutorial here to [Add a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops).

Check here to [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops), which will be triggered when a work item is created, and set the wiki url as the custom field value.

[image]

There is another workaround using azure pipeline and rest api.

Please check below steps:

1, create [web hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) to be triggered by `Work item created` event

When creating your webhook, you need to provide the following info:

- Request Url - `https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview`
- Secret - This is optional. If you need to secure your JSON payload, provide the Secret value

2, Create a new "Incoming Webhook" [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

- Webhook Name: The name of the webhook should match webhook created in your external service.

3, Create a [yaml pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser).

Add service connection resources in the yaml pipeline see below:

```
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: MyWebhookTrigger          
      connection: MyWebhookConnection   #the name of the Incoming Webhook service connection created in above step.
```

Add script task in your pipeline to call [work item update rest api.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) See below scripts:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    $workitemId= ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.resource.id}}
    $url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemId)?api-version=6.1-preview.3"

    $body ='
    [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
          "rel": "ArtifactLink",
          "url": "vstfs:///Wiki/WikiPage/{projectName}/{wikiName}/{wikiPage}",
          "attributes": {
            "name": "Wiki Page"
          }
        }
      }
    ]'

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Method patch -body $body
```

Please check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#resources-webhooks) for more information.

Above steps actually do below things:

New workitem is created-->automatically Trigger Azure pipeline-->Azure pipeline run script to call rest api to add the wiki page to the workitem.