# How to trigger a task on merged pull requests only?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure Devops, I have a repo that's in Bitbucket. I'd like to trigger a package publish on every *approved* pr that gets merged to the `develop` branch.

I've figured out how to conditionally run a task if the build is a pr or not, and how to trigger if the pr is to `develop`, but that means that the task is run for every PR created to `develop`. I'd like the task to only run when the pr has been *merged* to `develop`.

I noticed the following variables in my pipeline:

```
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_ISFORK=False
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_MERGEDAT=
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID=139
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTNUMBER=139
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEBRANCH=source-branch
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCECOMMITID=e55835e7e2e65ad87fd09a03959fefcfcc4d475f
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEREPOSITORYURI=[repoURL]
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_TARGETBRANCH=develop
```

And the `SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_MERGEDAT=` variable stood out. Anyone have suggestions? Am I overly complicating this?

Comment: If you want a task to run when something has been merged to `develop`, then the logical condition would be "is this build coming from `develop`?"

Comment: If you have your condition trigger on "is the build coming from develop", it would look something like this:
`condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'develop')]` 
However, this will mean the condition is true regardless of if the pr is merged or not -- in our devops, I see one build for the commit, and another for that same commit, but for the PR. If the pr is not yet approved, but is updated with another commit (say someone fixes something the reviewer asked) then there's another build. I don't want to publish a package until the pr is approved.

Comment: Ahh, if you utilize the build reason, and require build reason == pull request, then of the two triggered builds on an update to a pr, only one will have build reason = pull request as true. The one for the individual comit will have 
```
Evaluating: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
Expanded: eq('IndividualCI', 'PullRequest')
Result: False
```

Comment: still not sure how to limit the task to only run for an accepted pr -- i suspect the commonly accepted answer is "just use a webhook on the pr acceptance" but i still wonder if this is something you can pull off with just conditions.

Comment: Should you define a branch-policy to force merges only with PRs, branch filters also do the job. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#branches

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this with just conditions. Let's say you were merging from feature branch to develop branch. And you only want a task to be executed when the pr has been merged to develop.

First of all you should know the default CI triggers and PR triggers for Bitbucket repository on Azure pipeline.

1, **CI triggers**

> If you don't specify any triggers, the default is as if you wrote below, which means commit to any branch will trigger the pipeline.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
```

> When you specify a trigger, it replaces the default implicit trigger, and only pushes to branches that are explicitly configured to be included will trigger a pipeline. Includes are processed first, and then excludes are removed from that list.

2, **PR triggers**

> If no pr triggers appear in your YAML file, pull request validations are automatically enabled for all branches.

> When you specify a pr trigger, it replaces the default implicit pr trigger, and only pushes to branches that are explicitly configured to be included will trigger a pipeline.

> Each new run builds the latest commit from the **source branch** of the pull request. This is different from how Azure Pipelines builds pull requests in other repositories (e.g., Azure Repos or GitHub), where it builds the merge commit,

See the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information.

So if you don't specify any CI triggers or PR Triggers. The default behavior is to enable the triggers for all branches. And the PR triggers will only trigger the pipeline to build the last commit from the source branch(ie. Feature branch) instead of develop branch.

So it will explain why there are two triggered builds on an update to a pr. one is CI trigger(ie. IndividualCI), another is `PullRequest`.  Both builds were against the source branch (ie.feature).

When the pr was merged to develop. what happened was a new commit being added to develop branch, which will trigger the CI build. So the task you want to trigger should be run against develop branch.

As for above case of yours. I suggest you disable the pr triggers and only enable the CI triggers.(for pr triggers will only build the latest commit from the **source branch**, which is the same with CI trigger. )

You can disable the pr trigger like below:

```
pr: none
```

So you can just set the condition like below for the task

```
- task: taskname
  input: 

  condition: and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))
```

You can also use Webhook to trigger the azure pipeline. And set the condtion to `eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'ResourceTrigger')`

```
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: bitbucketwebhook          
      connection: bitbucketwebhook
```

[image]

Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261050/reference-wiki-page-from-inside-customized-work-item/66273801#66273801) for more information.